# Subset rows where string matches rows

Tags: r

I have following dataframe:

```
   Code       Eqpmnt
   123        501R
   234        602
   456        503
   546        504
   667        SK01
   789        507
   678        EK09
```

I want to keep rows where `Eqpmnt` starts with `5 0r 6` also Equipment name like `501R` which has `R` in the end should get converted to `501`

My Desired dataframe would be

```
  Code       Eqpmnt
  123        501
  234        602
  456        503
  546        504
  789        507
```

How can I achieve this in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An idea via base R,

```
df$Eqpmnt <- as.numeric(gsub('\\D+', '', df$Eqpmnt))
df[df$Eqpmnt %/% 100 %in% c(5, 6),]
```

which gives,

> ```
>    Code Eqpmnt
> 1  123    501
> 2  234    602
> 3  456    503
> 4  546    504
> 6  789    507
> ```

Answer (score 1):

base R solution similar to @Sotos:

Remove letters using `gsub()`, but extract using `grep` instead of `%in%`

```
df2 <- df[grep("^5|6", Eqpmnt)]
df2$Eqpmnt <- gsub("[A-Z]", "", df2$Eqpmnt)
```

> ```
>    ode Eqpmnt
> 1: 123    501
> 2: 234    602
> 3: 456    503
> 4: 546    504
> 5: 789    507
> ```

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse` solution using `dplyr` and `stringr` could be:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  filter(str_detect(str_sub(Eqpmnt, 1, 1), '5|6')) %>% 
  mutate(Eqpmnt = str_remove(Eqpmnt, "[A-Z]"))
```

We can avoid `str_sub` using `^` in regex as Sotos mentions:

```
df %>% 
  filter(str_detect(Eqpmnt, '^5|6')) %>% 
  mutate(Eqpmnt = str_remove(Eqpmnt, "[A-Z]"))
```

Returns:

```
  Code Eqpmnt
1  123    501
2  234    602
3  456    503
4  546    504
5  789    507
```

Comment: @Sotos updated my answer using `str_sub`, I believe this should fix the issue

Comment: Yup. However I am wondering If you can add an the start of the string `^` in `str_detect` and so avoid `str_sub`. I m no good with regex though so I don't know for sure :)

Comment: You are right again :) regex is also a mystery to me

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table` where we subset the data using `grep` and assing 'Eqpmnt' by removing the letter 'R' at the end

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[grepl('^[56]', Eqpmnt)][, Eqpmnt := sub("R$", "", Eqpmnt)][]
#   Code Eqpmnt
#1:  123    501
#2:  234    602
#3:  456    503
#4:  546    504
#5:  789    507
```

---

Or with `str_sub` and `str_remove` from `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
   filter(str_sub(Eqpmnt, 1, 1) %in% 5:6) %>%
   mutate(Eqpmnt = str_remove(Eqpmnt, "R$"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This actually only works for numeric. I misread your question.

```
library(dplyr)
filter(your_dataframe, between(Epmnt, 500, 599))
```

For character:

```
toy <- data.frame(x = paste(c(100, 200, 300, 400, 401, 410, 407, 408), sample(LETTERS, 8), sep = ""))
filter(toy, x %in% grep("^4|^3", x, value = TRUE))
     x
1 300J
2 400I
3 401Z
4 410C
5 407E
6 408W
```

Comment: Did you try that?

Comment: Still does not give required outcome

Comment: Did you try your v2?

Comment: The form works. There's an example if you would like to run it to confirm. I appreciate the feedback though, it needed more.

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Eqpmnt = gsub("[^\\d*]", "", df$Eqpmnt, perl = TRUE)) %>%
  filter(str_detect(df$Eqpmnt, "^5|6"))
```